# Special properties of this matrix

Tags: matrices

Given an invertible Vandermonde matrix $\mathbb{V}$, with randomly chosen knots $(v_0,v_1 \dots v_{N-1})$ on the unit circle, what can be said about the matrix:

$$\mathbb{A}= 
\mathbb{V}^{-1}.
diag(v_0^N,v_1^N \dots, v_{N-1}^N) . \mathbb{V}
$$

I know that it can be expressed as the $n^{th}$ power of the companion matrix corresponding to the roots. Does it have any special properties as such, or asymptotically?

Comment: A property that is a direct consequence is that the eigenvectors of this companion matrix (and thus to any of its powers) are the columns of $V$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I am aware of that property. Are there any others you know?